# How does one strip tags (and their content) from an HTML string using PHP's DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'd like to remove all links **and their contents** from an HTML string.

So this ...
`<a href="#">LINK1</a> and <i>also</i> <a href="#">LINK2</a>` ... should become this: `and <i>also</i>`

The following ...

```php
$html = '<a href="#">LINK1</a> - and <i>also</i> <a href="#">LINK2</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = false;
$dom->resolveExternals = false;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
$dom->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
while ($list->length > 0) {
    $p = $list->item(0);
    $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);
}
$html_new = $dom->saveHTML();

echo htmlentities($html);
echo '<br><br><hr><br>';
echo htmlentities($html_new);
```

... does not work unless I wrap `$html` in a `<div>`, but then I have `<div> and <i>also</i> </div>`. I could use `substr` to strip the first 5 and last 6 characters off the result, but that's just stupid, and my face is already too sore from all the face-palming I've endured trying to figure out the above.

Any advice on how to strip all tags out of a string **without using regex**, or resorting to facepalmy hacks?

Comment: Since `DOMDocument` expects a *document*, not a DocumentFragment, you do indeed need to wrap it in a parent container and then strip that parent container afterward. It's not "stupid", that's the way you have to do it :)

Comment: I guess that's why helper classes exist :) Alright, I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **Niet the Dark Absol**'s comment, my solution was to simply wrap my code nippet in a `div`, and then use `substr` to remove it. Seems like an acceptable workaround for working with valid inline HTML snippets (and not the entire DOM) via DOMDocument.

```php
$html = '<a href="#">LINK1</a> - and <i>also</i> <a href="#">LINK2</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = false;
$dom->resolveExternals = false;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
$dom->loadHTML( '<div>'.$html.'</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
while ($list->length > 0) {
    $p = $list->item(0);
    $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);
}

$result = substr($dom->saveHTML(), 5, -6);
```